# TabTip.exe The requested operation requires elevation. .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

TabTip.exe The requested operation require

### I am trying to get TabTip to pop up when a function is called. I am trying to do this with this code in .NET Core but I get the following error:

{System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The requested operation requires elevation
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at myfunc() in myClass.cs:line 64}

### Here is the Code

```
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\TabTip.exe");
    p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    p.Start();
```

I am running Visual Studio in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I used to complete what I was trying to accomplish. I needed to copy TabTip.exe from its original location to my project's directory.

```
            var processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (var process in processlist.Where(process => process.ProcessName == "TabTip"))
            {
                process.Kill();
                break;
            }

            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.Start();

            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(".\\TabTip.exe");
            cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
            cmd.StandardInput.Dispose();
            cmd.WaitForExit();
            Debug.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems not be working: The term '.\TabTip.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program.